# Is SDL_LockSurface needed to access the pixel format?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-1.2

`SDL_LockSurface`'s [documentation](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdllocksurface.html) suggests, not very clearly, that pixel format of some surfaces may change during their lifetime, and so the proper way to access a surface's pixel format would be to first check if the surface needs locking with `SDL_MUSTLOCK`, and if so, lock it using `SDL_LockSurface`.

However, a lot of online [code samples](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson05/) access the format without performing either check.

Is locking the surface really necessary to access the pixel format? Can the format change during surface lifetime so as to require locking?

I'm using SDL 1.2 in case there's any difference between versions.

Comment: The problem with surfaces is they may reside in video memory, rather than in the directly accessible 'regular' memory -- or a combination (such as a RAM cached version). It depends on the video driver and card, and therefore I think you should *always* check `SDL_MUSTLOCK`. (Typically, I only check `SDL_MUSTLOCK` right before a global screen update and not inside a 'per pixel' routine.)

Comment: I have a switch statement inside a loop in which, only in some of the cases, I need to construct colors to use with functions that don't need explicit locking, e.g. `SDL_FillRect` - so I need to access the surface's pixel format just for the color. I was thinking of fetching the format before the loop as early as possible, or even when the surface is created, but I'm not sure if there's a possibility for it to go "stale" before I use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unlikely that the pixel format will be changed and if it does, then it wouldn't happen in the middle of your accessing it because the format resides in client memory (touched only by you and SDL).  If you still feel concerned about the possibility, then always create surfaces with the SDL_SWSURFACE flag or lock the surface before accessing the format.